# Getting javax.servlet.jsp.JSP Exception(see stack trace), can anyone please help to figure it out?

Tags: jsp, struts, jdeveloper

I'm getting JSP Exception while running my struts application through JDeveloper 11, it says No getter method, while I've written getter method for Property "ServiceProvider_Id". Please check below logs for details :

```
Error 500--Internal Server Error
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: No getter method for property: "ServiceProvider_Id" of bean: "ManageServiceProviderForm"
at org.apache.struts.taglib.TagUtils.lookup(TagUtils.java:915)
at org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag.doStartTag(WriteTag.java:233)
at jsp_servlet.__manageserviceprovider._jsp__tag3(__manageserviceprovider.java:262)
at jsp_servlet.__manageserviceprovider._jsp__tag0(__manageserviceprovider.java:145)
at jsp_servlet.__manageserviceprovider._jspService(__manageserviceprovider.java:100)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:416)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:326)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at oracle.dms.wls.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:330)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Comment: can u share getter method here, and try to follow naming convention... it should be serviceProvider_Id.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your class structure, i would suggest looking into 1 of the following:

1. the property / name in the jsp has ServiceProvider_Id when it should be serviceProvider_Id
2. the get method name is correct, and with no parameters
3. the first found ManageServiceProviderForm class on your classpath contains ServiceProvider_Id